# ubuntu 16.04 is blocked in startup

Tags: startup

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and today is blocked he in startup here

[image]

Comment: Does it stops there as shown in the photo? Have you tried to wait longer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience i see this as a kernel error. I had a similar problem in which my system wasn't shutting down just getting as stuck as yours. When starting your system, choose advanced options from the GRUB menu and select a different kernel and it should boot properly.

GRUB menu:
    [Here is the GRUB menu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SCkc.jpg)

And you should see a kernel list here:
[Select a lower version of kernel (generic) from the menu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gWGy.png)

This should start your system properly.

Comment: Thank you , but no he freezes at the logo on startup :(

Comment: @hous GRUB menu appears before the startup of ubuntu. The picture you posted above is log of kernel which loads after GRUB. If you don't see the GRUB menu see this.https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time