# Ubuntu 18.04 not booting after installation

Tags: boot

I recently wiped my hard-disk  and tried installing Ubuntu 18.04 but after completion of installation,its not booting .Its just showing ubuntu logo .
My computer hardware is bit old .Can it be the reason for its non compatibility for not booting?
Please help..

Comment: I would create a brand new install Live USB from a fresh download if 18.04 and install again. If it still doesn't work I would repeat the process with 16.04 which has a proven track record.

Comment: This may be a problem with the Intel i915 video controller. See my question at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036242/17-10-to-18-04-upgrade-freezes-during-boot-need-video-controller-kernel-paramet and try using the i915.modeset=0 parameter to see if it gets you booting.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/974711/758023